# Alfresco 5.2 : JavaScript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I custom "activiti-transitions.js" file and working done in CHROME.

But not working in IE. 
(In my IE - JavaScript is enabled)
My script not working:

```
  onClick: function ActivitiTransitions_onClick(e, p_obj)
  {   
      var me = this;
      var buttonId = p_obj.get("id");   
      //NEW
      if(buttonId.includes("Reject") 
      ){
        var dashboardUri = Alfresco.util.uriTemplate("userdashboardpage",
         {
            userid: encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.constants.USERNAME)
         });
     Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
         {
            title: $msg("Title),
            text: $msg("Content"),
            buttons: [
               {
                 text: $msg("OK"),
                  handler: function onOK()
                  {
                    this.destroy();
                    me._onClickOk.call(me, p_obj)
                    window.location = dashboardUri;
                  }
               },
               {
                 text: $msg("Cancle"),
                 handler: function onCancel()
                 {
                   this.destroy();
                   window.location = dashboardUri;
                 },
                  isDefault: true
               }]
         });  
      }else{
     Alfresco.util.submitForm(p_obj.getForm());               
     }
```

}

Please help me!

Comment: `not working` - check the browser developer tools console for errors - your code, as written in the question won't work in any browser since you have a missing `"` (line 14 in your code here) - and a friendly suggestion ... **format your code**

Comment: also, check IE11 is not running in some emulation mode, which could be causing issues

Comment: You would just want to check your IE version and Alfresco version in the Alfresco's supported stack/compatibility matrix - https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/supported-platforms-ACS.html